# <lightning:input type="date" validation

Tags: lightning, validation, date

I need to put a validation on lightning input field date. It is a date of birth field and it should not accept date beyond system.today().
Basically the validation will be
date_Of_birth > Today() , then there should an error message.

The error message should display beside the lightning input field.

Is it possible? can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in validation logic of the `lightning:input` component.

There is a `max` attribute on the `lightning:input` component in which you need to provide the max date value in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format - [documenation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation).
[image: lightning:input - date value validation]

To get today's date you will need to use the JS Controller - on init of your component call function to prepare today's date in the correct format:

```
new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

Let's store the prepared date value in the `todaysDate` aura attribute (remember to declare such attribute in your `.cmp` file):

```
component.set('v.todaysDate', new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Now you can finally use the `todaysDate` aura attribute in the `max` attribute of the `lightning:input`:

```
max="{!v.todaysDate}"
```

**DEMO**

[image: Day Of Birth - max value validation]

**FINAL FILES**

`DayOfBirthInputValidation.cmp`

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    
    <aura:attribute name="todaysDate" type="String"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
    
    <lightning:card>
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme_shade slds-theme_alert-texture slds-m-around_medium">
            Today is: <b>{!v.todaysDate}</b>
        </div>
        <lightning:input
                         label="Day Of Birth"
                         type="date"
                         dateStyle="short"
                         max="{!v.todaysDate}"
                         class="slds-p-around_medium"
        />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

`DayOfBirthInputValidationController.js`

```
({
    onInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.todaysDate', new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764400/lightninginput-date-field-validation).

In the controller replace the dateRange variables with the current date:

```
var today = new Date(); //returns date time.
```

If you need Time to be 00:00:00 then set it for today before comparing:

```
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```